# Syntax error in INSERT INTO parameter query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I try `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` I get an error saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

I posted this same problem [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20356025/2144390)... can someone help me again?

```
Private Sub btnadd1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd1.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Printlist1 As New DataTable
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=c:Database11.accdb"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
    End If

    If Me.text1.Tag & "" = "" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Printlist1(StickerCode, Description, Company, Department, Location, User, SerialNumber, DatePurchased, Tagable, Quantity, Brand, Model)" & _
                    " VALUES(@StickerCode, @Description, @Company, @Department, @Location, @User, @SerialNumber, @DatePurchased, @Tagable, @Quantity, @Brand, @Model)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StickerCode", Me.text1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Me.text2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", Me.text3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", Me.text4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Me.text5.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", Me.text6.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", Me.text7.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePurchased", Me.text8.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tagable", Me.text9.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Me.text10.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", Me.text11.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Me.text12.Text)

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else


        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Printlist1 " & _
                    " SET StickerCode='" & Me.text1.Text & _
                    ", Description='" & Me.text2.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Company='" & Me.text3.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Department='" & Me.text4.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Location='" & Me.text5.Text & "'" & _
                    ", User='" & Me.text6.Text & "'" & _
                    ", SerialNumber='" & Me.text7.Text & "'" & _
                    ", DatePurchased='" & Me.text8.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Tagable='" & Me.text9.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Quantity='" & Me.text10.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Brand='" & Me.text11.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Model='" & Me.text12.Text & "'" & _
                    " WHERE text1=" & Me.text1.Tag


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If
    RefreshData()
    Me.btnclear1.PerformClick()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Sticker Code    Description Company Department  Location    User    Serial Number   Date Purchased  Tagable Quantity    Brand   Model

Comment: can you share table structure for `Printlist1`

Comment: The else logic (update) should also use parameters, but has nothing to do with your current issue.  What is the actual error? Go into the inner exception if  you have to find one, and a stack trace is also useful.

Comment: @dbw i dont know how to share to you the table structure of Printlist1

Comment: @ps2goat how to user the parameters ins else logic(update)?

Comment: @user3049808 just edit your question and place the table structure at end

Comment: For example, use the same type of parameters as you do with the insert, then use code similar to: `UPDATE Printlist1 SET StickerCode = @StickerCode Where text1 = @text1` (create a new parameter on the command and set its value to Me.text1.Text like you do with other parameters)

Comment: @dbw done did you see now?

Comment: @user3049808 Table structure you added contains column name as `Sticker Code` or it is `StickerCode` without spaces

Answer (score 3):

User is a reserved word in Sql try placing it in Square Brackets like this [User]

---

```
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Printlist1(StickerCode, [Description], Company, Department, Location, [User], SerialNumber, DatePurchased, Tagable, Quantity, Brand, Model)" & _
                " VALUES(@StickerCode, @Description, @Company, @Department, @Location, @User, @SerialNumber, @DatePurchased, @Tagable, @Quantity, @Brand, @Model)"
```

Comment: it didnt work my friend

Comment: `Description` is also a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).